# fseek ftell reading same input

Tags: c, fseek, ftell

I am trying to get my program to read one line at a time for each child (each line contains one int).  Every time I perform this read, it keeps reading the first line.

Here is the basis of my code.

```
void forkChildren (int nChildren) {
int i;
int size;
int sum = 0;
int tell = 0;
pid_t pid;
for (i = 0; i < nChildren; i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        /* error handling here, if needed */
        return;
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        char data[10];
        FILE * file1;
        file1 = fopen("numbers.dat", "r");
        fseek(file1, tell, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(data, 10, file1);
        //fseek(file1, tell, SEEK_SET);
        tell += strlen(data); 
        printf("%d ", tell);
        sum = atoi(data);
        printf("Sum is: %d \n", sum);
        sleep (5);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You are fseeking to the same offset from the beginning of the file in all the child processes. If that isn't what you want, tell us what you do want.

Comment: Even thought I'm increasing "tell" every time I perform a read? Or does this only increase the tell for that child?

Comment: It only increases tell for each child because (a) each child is operating on a different (unique) file descriptor and (b) the variable "tell" is a separate copy in each child.  You can add to tell in one and the others (nor the parent) will ever know the difference.

Comment: So, uhm, you're using level 3 buffered io on the same file as multiple child processes manipulate the same file? Why don't you (a) use pipes to avoid going thru the file system, or (b) use a file-per-child? Each child inherits their own, private copy of `tell`, but that means that they all share the default value of 0 from the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fork, each child has its own [PCB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block). Since you open the file **after** the fork, then each child has it's own separate file descriptor, offset, etc.
If you want child processes to share the same file descriptor and offset, they have to point to the same file descriptor the kernel creates. For this, you have to open the file **before** the fork.
[Read here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for more information.

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors...

In your code, you try to keep track of the position in the file by using `int tell`, but this variable is **not** shared between the child processes. Instead, use a shared file descriptor and the kernel will keep track of the offset for you.

Comment: What happens if I want to skip a line using this process?

Comment: Once you fork, you loose synchronicity between child processes, as now the timing is controlled by the kernel. This means that operations on shared resources is somewhat unpredictable. You can skip lines if you want, but it's hard to guarantee when (in relation to the other children) this will happen.